Align header across grid items
I have three grid items in a row, each with its h2 element. One element's content is too long, so it is wrapped. Due to the wrapping, elements in grid items look misaligned. So I need the headings have the same height, as the most tall element, and if the text height is lesser than the header height, it should be centered inside it.
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="product">
    <h2>Header 2</h2>
    <h3>$10</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>Very very very long header 2</h2>
    <h3>$20</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>Header 3</h2>
    <h3>$30</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</div>

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-template-column: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.product h2,
.product h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

I tried to solve this with display: grid property of .product elements like so:
.product {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

This is not as responsive, as I need: text may not be wrapped on some screen widths, but the size of the cell remains the same (and it will look like a crutch to write media queries for it). Also, when the header text is wrapped, other header's text appears on top of .product elements, which leads to the gap between h2 and h3.
